# How do we recurse through this table?

Tags: sqlite

I have a simple family tree table that includes:

```
PIN Numeric, primary key
FATHER_PIN  ID of father
MOTHER_PIN  ID of mother
```

I want to recurse through the tree with:

```
WITH RECURSIVE
  parent_of(PIN, parent) AS
    (SELECT PIN, MOTHER_PIN FROM PERSONS UNION SELECT PIN, FATHER_PIN FROM PERSONS),
  ancestor_of_alice(PIN) AS
    (SELECT parent FROM parent_of WHERE PIN = 1
     UNION ALL
     SELECT parent FROM parent_of JOIN ancestor_of_alice USING(PIN))
SELECT PERSONS.PIN FROM ancestor_of_alice, PERSONS
 WHERE ancestor_of_alice.PIN = PERSONS.PIN
 ORDER BY PIN;
```

I am getting an error "ambiguous column name: PIN"

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

> I am getting an error "ambiguous column name: PIN"

An ambiguous column error means you are referencing a column in your query that exists in multiple objects being referenced in that query, without specifying the name of which object you want that column to be used from.

In your specific query, the issue is your `ORDER BY` clause which says `ORDER BY PIN;`. It doesn't matter that the value of that column will be the same regardless of which object it's used from, syntactically it's still required you specify which object you're referencing. This is because the SQL engine wouldn't know that the value would be the same either way, until runtime.

To fix your issue, assumptively you probably want to write the code as `ORDER BY PERSONS.PIN;`.

Comment: Yes, that works! Thank you! However, the query now goes into an infinite loop. Why?

Here is a small test set: http://findyourfamilytree.com/upload/kennedy2.DB

Comment: @Pierre I'm unable to download that. If you want to make an example, you can use [dbfiddle.uk](https://www.dbfiddle.uk). But your problem is likely this line of code `JOIN ancestor_of_alice USING(PIN)`. This isn't crawling the family tree recursively, instead it's just joining on the same parent `PIN` over and over again. You need to join the child `PIN` to the next ancestor (parent) `PIN` to get who they're a parent of, etc. Probably something like `JOIN ancestor_of_alice ON parent_of.ChildPIN = ancestor_of_alice.PIN`. You'll need to add the child PIN to your CTEs and `SELECT` lost too.